# Google Cloud SDK Init web authentication error

Tags: sdk

I installed Google Cloud SDK on Mac and then ran the command `./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init` but every time I do this I get the following errors:

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUWUc.png)

it comes up with the prompt to log in and choose an account but then every time I click on my google account it tries to load and then I get a safari cannot connect to server error.

I have also tried running `./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud auth login` with the same errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try running it without opening the browser?

```
gcloud auth login --no-launch-browser
```

Comment: yes I tried that yesterday and it was giving me the same error where the safari server wasn't loading.  However today when I pasted the link into my browser it would load and give me the code I needed. Not sure if something was wrong with their servers last night or not.  Thanks for the help